# proof of integration formula for power of cosine

Tags: calculus

I want to know the proof of the following formula.
$\int\cos^m\theta d\theta=\frac{1}{m}\sin\theta cos^{m-1}\theta+\frac{m-1}{m}\int\cos^{m-2}\theta d\theta$
There is another formula for sine function.Can anyone prove both the formula with better explanation?

Answer (score 1):

This is really integration by part.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}\int \cos^m x dx &= \int \cos^{m-1} x \cos xdx \\
&= \int \cos^{m-1}x d(\sin x)\\
&= \cos^{m-1}x\sin x - \int \sin x d(\cos^{m-1} x)\ \ \ \ \ \  \left(\int \text{ by part}\right)\\
&= \cos^{m-1}x\sin x - \int \sin x (m-1) \cos^{m-2} x (-\sin x) dx \\
&= \cos^{m-1}x\sin x + (m-1)\int \sin ^2x \cos^{m-2} x dx \\
&= \cos^{m-1}x\sin x + (m-1) \int (1- \cos^2 x) \cos^{m-2} x dx \ \ \ \ \ (\cos^2 x + \sin ^2 x = 1)\\ 
&= \cos^{m-1}x\sin x + (m-1) \int \cos^{m-2} x dx - (m-1)\int \cos^m x dx  
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now move the the last term on the right hand side to obtain

$$m \int \cos^m x dx =  \cos^{m-1}x\sin x + (m-1) \int \cos^{m-2} x dx$$

When you divide both sides by $m$, you obtain the reduction formula for $\cos^mx$. That of $\sin^m x$ can be similarly deduced.